# JSON parsing. Unexpected character (t) at position 2. JAVA

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse JSON data from a google maps search. 
I've tryed both JACKSON and and now I'm Trying JSON SIMPLE. Both of them gives the same error.

First of all I'm doing an search on Google maps.

```
String urlString = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&output=json&start=0&q="+ "Stockholm" + "+Gym";
```

Gives me JSON while(1);{title:"stockholm Gym - Google Maps",url:"/maps?f=q\x26source=s_q\x26start=0\x26q=stockholm+Gym\x26ie=UTF8\x26hq=Gym.............. and so on.
I'm replacing the while(1); with ""; before i return the string.

To the problem when I'm trying to parse it

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    String jsonString = "";
```

// UriHandler.mapSearchJson is the method that returns the jsonString.

```
    String jsonData = UriHandler.mapSearchJSON(jsonString);

    Object obj = "";
    try {

        obj = parser.parse(jsonData);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;

    String title = (String) jsonObj.get("title");
    System.out.println(title);
```

This gives me the exception.
Unexpected character (t) at position 2.

When I'm debbuging it. comes all the way to when it's trying to parse the string. then the obj is = null.

What in thw world am I doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the rules for JSON are stricter than the rules for JavaScript object literals.  Unquoted field names are OK in object literals, but not in JSON.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the others already mentioned, a nonquoted field name is not standard JSON.  However, Jackson (and maybe others) has a [set of option settings](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeaturesNonStandard) that allow it to work with nonstandard, but common JSON derivatives:

```
JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES
```

will enable processing of unquoted field names.

Answer (score 2):

The response is not valid JSON, as the key name was not quoted with double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

> {title:"stockholm Gym"

is invalid JSON, it should be this:

```
{"title":"stockholm Gym"
```

Notice how `title` is surrounded by `"` double quotes

Answer (score 2):

You are pulling back Javascript **code** that is meant for the `maps.google.com` site to use.

There could be any Javascript code in that response, not just the JSON that happens to be returned as part of the search.

You need to request from their maps API instead:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Stockholm+Gym&sensor=false

This will return you only the JSON data.

Have a look the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error when trying to parse the json returned from kafka (kafka twitter producer).

The message returned was including some extra text other than json (KeyedMessage(twitter-test_english,null,null). Because of that I was facing this error.

```
KeyedMessage(twitter-test_english,null,null,{"created_at":"Sat Apr 23 18:31:10 +0000 2016","id":723942306777337856,"id_str":"723942306777337856"}
```

Pass only the message part from returned json and convert it into string.

```
{"created_at":"Sat Apr 23 18:31:10 +0000 2016","id":723942306777337856,"id_str":"723942306777337856"}

message = new KeyedMessage("twitter-test_english", (String)queue.take());
//System.out.println("This is message"+message.message());
String message_string = message.message().toString();
JsonParse.toParseJson(message_string);
```